# Sending an item to be inside the scrollView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I created a segmentedControl and add it as subView during viewDidLoad. I faced a problem whereby it doesn't scroll.

How do I add a subView to be inside the scrollView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out...

[scrollView addSubview:segmentedControl];

Comment: @EmptyStack Not before I asked this question. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

[scrollView addSubview:segmentedControl];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(s.frame.size.width, 1000);

change height accordingly your segmentedControl height.

if your segmentedControl is fit in scrollview it would not scroll.